# Issue with Data Loading from Database in a WinForms Application using DevExpress in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, database, winforms, devexpress-gridcontrol

Hello :) I am trying to create a desktop WinForms application in Visual Studio 2022 and am using DevExpress. I have created a welcome screen with a menu, where clicking on a button opens a form with products. On this form, I have placed 2 grids separated by a splitter. I am loading the database from MS SQL using the Data Source Wizard. So far, I have only one record stored in it for testing. Both grids are set to winExplorerView, and to set the appearance of the grid, I used the E-Commerce Item Template, which I slightly modified. The problem I have is that the application connects to the database, but when I run the application, it does not display data from the database. Yet, it seems that I have everything set up correctly. Can someone please advise me on what to do?